# Access a pdf file from views.py which is created by Js in a Django project

Tags: javascript, html, django, pdf

I am trying to render with `HTML` to pdf in my `Django` project. I am using [html2pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2pdf.js/v/0.9.0) package form js and render my `html` into pdf by following link: [youtubelink](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DcN-AL6lXaY).

my template:

```
<div class="container-fluid py-5 bg-light">
  <div class="col-xl-10 bg-white" id="pdf_portion">
    <p>Lots of staff is in this div. I just skip those unnecessary things in this question.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-primary" id="download"> download pdf</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2pdf.js/0.9.2/html2pdf.bundle.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("download")
        .addEventListener("click", () => {
            const invoice = this.document.getElementById("pdf_portion");
            console.log(invoice);
            console.log(window);
            var opt = {
                margin: 0.8,
                filename: 'myfile.pdf',
                image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
                html2canvas: { scale: 4 },
                jsPDF: { unit: 'in', format: 'A4', orientation: 'portrait' }
            };
            html2pdf().from(invoice).set(opt).save();
        })
  }
</script>
```

Here the 'download' button gives us the option to download the pdf. I need to send the pdf in my `views.py` in any method, thus I will able to save it in my database's `filefield`.

**Please suggest How can I able to access that pdf file in my views.py.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The html2pdf package comes with the functionality to handle the generated pdf instead of directly downloading them. It's outputPdf function takes the desired data format as input and returns the output.

Currently supported data-formats are:

- arraybuffer
- blob
- bloburi
- datauristring
- datauri

It can be used as followed:

```
const elem = document.getElementById('html'); //element whose pdf is to be made

html2pdf().from(elem).outputPdf('arraybuffer').then((result) => {
 // write your desired code here for sendin results to django views
});
```

Now in order to send this data to backend, you can simply use AJAX post request in this function.

Comment: I am not familiar with `AJAX` too much. Can you please suggest to me the `AJAX post request ` too?

Comment: If you are familiar with javascript, [this](https://dev.to/coderasha/how-to-send-django-form-with-ajax-4bpo) blog can help you get started with using Ajax for sending data to django backend.